# Why mutiple local jar under a same maven groupId, artifactId and version?

Tags: maven

I'm modifying the version of a jar config from 1.0.28 to 1.0.29-SNAPSHOT in my pom.xml for updating it. But I've found two jars in my local repository folder. Specially, the central repository is maintained by my company.

The maven version I've used is 2.2.1, and the version of jdk is 1.8.0_151

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.my.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>common</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.29-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

I only need common-1.0.29-SNAPSHOT.jar. But I don't know why there is common-1.0.29-20181228.142316-1.jar here.

This is the file list on my computer:

```
-rw-r--r--    1    staff    staff    255     Dec    29    10:04    _remoterepositories
-rw-r--r--    1    staff    staff    371     Jan    2     09:53    maven-metadata-centralxml
-rw-r--r--    1    staff    staff    41      Jan    2     09:53    maven-metadata-centralxmlsha1
-rw-r--r--    1    staff    staff    1002    Jan    2     09:51    maven-metadata-mirror-allxml
-rw-r--r--    1    staff    staff    41      Jan    2     09:51    maven-metadata-mirror-allxmlsha1
-rw-r--r--    1    staff    staff    191     Jan    2     09:51    resolver-statusproperties
-rw-r--r--    1    staff    staff    48058   Dec    29    10:04    common-1029-20181228142316-1jar
-rw-r--r--    1    staff    staff    40      Dec    29    10:04    common-1029-20181228142316-1jarsha1
-rw-r--r--    1    staff    staff    7801    Dec    29    10:04    common-1029-20181228142316-1pom
-rw-r--r--    1    staff    staff    40      Dec    29    10:04    common-1029-20181228142316-1pomsha1
-rw-r--r--    1    staff    staff    48058   Dec    29    10:04    common-1029-SNAPSHOTjar
-rw-r--r--    1    staff    staff    7801    Dec    29    10:04    common-1029-SNAPSHOTpom
```

Comment: Really using Maven 2? Please upgrade as soon as possible to Maven 3.6.0...Maven 2 is End Of Live

Answer (score 0):

This is how Maven keeps track of what `-SNAPSHOT` actually *means* in  the local repository.  It is the timestamp for (if I recall correctly) when the artifact was installed.

A guess could be that a copy is kept in case an install process does not succeed for rollback.